# Azure VM not connecting to Azure Redis Cache but local is connecting to Azure Redis Cache

Tags: node.js, caching, redis, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

The same Azure Redis cache is getting connected from local machince.
The port 6380, on which cache is running is open in firewall of both inbound and outbound in the VM.

[image]

I tried in both NodeJs and Java. Both are connecting to remote Azure Redis from local and the exact same code for NodeJS and Java is not connceting to Azure Redis cache from VM.

Java config:

```
spring.redis.host=my-cache.redis.cache.windows.net

spring.redis.password=<password>

spring.redis.port=6380

spring.redis.ssl=true
```

NodeJS config:

```
const client = redis.createClient(6380,
  'my-cache.redis.cache.windows.net',
  {
    auth_pass: <password>,
    tls: { servername: 'my-cache.redis.cache.windows.net' }
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solved by the following on my Windows Desktop VM:

1. Click Start.
2. Enter cmd in the Start menu search text box.
3. Right-click Command Prompt and select Run as Administrator.
4. Run the following command: ipconfig /flushdns
5. Run the following command: ipconfig /registerdns

Answer (score 0):

well, the other end must accept connection as well, so you mist allow connections from the VM if you have any firewall rules at all:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#firewall

Comment: All connections are allowed there. I can connect from any IP. That's why I'm able to connect from local.

Comment: well, i'd suggest checking the networking config on the vnet, by default NSG doesn't block outbound connectivity to internet so the connection should work unless there is something fancy going on like User Defined Routes, or another NSG that's actually blocking the traffic.

Comment: that doesnt mean a lot